# Limit the range of forecast values for R forecast package

Tags: r, forecasting

I am performing time series modeling and plotting the eventual forecasts using R's forecast package and the base plot() function.

The final forecasts are negative although this doesn't make sense for the data (the floor is 0).  Is there a way for me to tell the forecast function to limit the y-value prediction?

Answer (score 0):

After writing it out, I helped myself find the right search terms.  Here is the answer:

[image]

http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-within-limits/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer to this specific question here, and provide the link for reference.